# Unmet dependencies for packages required to compile FFmpeg

Tags: apt, dependencies, ffmpeg

I tried following the instructions from "How to compile FFmpeg for Ubuntu" at [Compile FFmpeg for Ubuntu, Debian, or Mint](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/CompilationGuide/Ubuntu).

These are:

```bsh
sudo apt-get update -qq && sudo apt-get -y install \
  autoconf \
  automake \
  build-essential \
  cmake \
  git-core \
  libass-dev \
  libfreetype6-dev \
  libgnutls28-dev \
  libsdl2-dev \
  libtool \
  libva-dev \
  libvdpau-dev \
  libvorbis-dev \
  libxcb1-dev \
  libxcb-shm0-dev \
  libxcb-xfixes0-dev \
  pkg-config \
  texinfo \
  wget \
  yasm \
  zlib1g-dev
```

However, I get:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies.
 libsdl2-dev : Depends: libsdl2-2.0-0 (= 2.0.8+dfsg1-1ubuntu1.18.04.4) but 2.0.9+dfsg1-1ubuntu1 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I enable the "Universe" repository?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/148638/how-do-i-enable-the-universe-repository). And please note that running `sudo apt-get build-dep ffmpeg` is simpler way to get package build-dependencies.

Answer (score 1):

Solved by:

```bsh
sudo apt-get install libsdl2-2.0-0/bionic
```

...and let it remove the 32-bit version of libsdl2.